# "Tom played Mary a joke." is not natural?

Tags: transitivity, ditransitive-verbs

I think "Tom played Mary a joke." is not natural and "Tom played a joke on Mary." is natural. What is your opinion?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Without knowing what you *intend* to say, we cannot help you except by guessing. Please [edit] your post to state explicitly in other words the scenario you are trying to describe. Both *Tom played Mary a joke* and *Tom played a joke on Mary* are acceptable English, but they mean very different things.

Answer (score 8):

OP is quite right that native speakers normally avoid the "ditransitive" construction (direct *and* indirect object, no preposition) with ***play*** [a joke]. Google Books has just 2 written instances of [*(She) played **him a joke***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22played%20him%20a%20joke%22). We much prefer the "monotransitive" version of that, with an explicitly-specified preposition (there are 2220 hits for [*...played a joke **on him***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22played%20a%20joke%20on%20him%22)).

But I should point out that Google Books has 5450 hits for the ditransitive [*(She) played him a **trick***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22played%20him%20a%20trick%22), which is almost as common as monotransitive [*...played a trick on him*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22played%20a%20trick%20on%20him%22) (5920 hits).

Some native speakers (mainly Americans) will feel a bit uneasy about the ditransitive usage with ***trick*** - it really depends on whether they draw a parallel with the non-idiomatic *play (him) a **trick*** or the perfectly natural *play (him) a **song***.

---

To the extent that there's any "logic" involved here - as opposed to a totally meaningless choice based purely on what one hears other people say (a matter of "idiomatically established" usage) - I think the difference turns on the nature of the relationship between the indirect object *(**him**)* and the direct object *(**joke, song**)*.

If we *do* include a preposition with ***song***, we can choose between ***to*** and ***for***. But we can't use ***on***, because that doesn't work with a ["Benefactive object"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door) (***him***, where ***he*** gets the "benefit" of hearing the song).

The link in that previous sentence is to a closely-related ELU question, where professor of linguistics John Lawler asserts that the prepositionless ditransitive form is *only* appropriate in "benefactive" contexts *where the indirect object (the "beneficiary") ends up **possessing** the direct object* (which he doesn't with ***door, joke***). So according to him, *Please open the door for me* cannot validly be transformed into *Please open me the door*. But if you follow that link, you'll see that not everyone agrees on this point - in particular, BrE speakers (such as myself) are more relaxed about such usages than AmE speakers.

I'm not really an expert on using mathematical expressions in Google NGrams, but I *think* if you compare [this AmE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played%20a%20trick%20on%20him%2Fplayed%20him%20a%20trick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28played%20a%20trick%20on%20him%20/%20played%20him%20a%20trick%29%3B%2Cc0) and [this BrE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played%20a%20trick%20on%20him%2Fplayed%20him%20a%20trick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28played%20a%20trick%20on%20him%20/%20played%20him%20a%20trick%29%3B%2Cc0) (for relative prevalence of ***played a trick on him*** and ***played him a trick***), what it shows is that the ditransitive form is twice as likely in BrE.

---

TL;DR - The ditransive (prepositionless) form is fine with ***play + song***, but not with ***play + joke***. But things aren't so clear-cut with ditransitive ***play + trick*** (which is more likely to be acceptable in BrE than in AmE), so if you want to play safe you should probably think in terms of including the preposition in any context where you're not sure.

---

EDIT: Reflecting comments made below, I should point out that the specific ditransitive usage *play [**someone**] a trick* has massively declined in popularity since the 1800s. So it would usually be seen today as a "dated" usage - another good reason to avoid it if you're not a native speaker who's well aware of such implications.

Comment: Worth noting: A good number of those "played him a trick" hits were penned in the 1800s.

Comment: @J.R.: You're quite right. As I said, I'm no expert on using mathematical expressions in Google NGrams - but I *also* think that both the AmE and BrE charts are indicating "near-parity" between ditransitive & "monotransitive + preposition" until about the start of C20. I was going to mention that ***played him a trick*** sounded more than a little "dated" even to my BrE ear, but I thought the answer was already getting a bit too long. And the truth is I couldn't easily square that with my "Brits are more accommodating / less dogmatic" sideswipe anyway, so I just left it out! :(

Comment: ...I could also have "digressed" into looking at what I consider to be the perfectly idiomatic ditransitive usage [***to play (someone) a blinder**.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53272/2637). Not common among AmE speakers, I think, but it's natural enough in colloquial BrE with the sense of *defeat / trick someone by successfully executing a deceptive/cunning plan*. Again though, the "recipient" doesn't end up "possessing" the direct object (the "blindingly impressive" ploy) - as with ***trick***, he ends up being ***subjected***  to it (as a victim, not a beneficiary).

Comment: Speaking of NGrams, here's a [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+him+a+trick%2Cplayed+a+trick+on+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplayed%20him%20a%20trick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplayed%20a%20trick%20on%20him%3B%2Cc0) showing that "played him a trick" was more common before World War II and "played a trick on him" has been more common since then.

Comment: Played him a trick might be referring to hand in the card game Bridge.

Comment: @jmoreno: *I've played me a lot of bridge over the years.* Admittedly that's not a very likely example of "ditransitive **play**" in the context of bridge, but at least it's "credible" (even if it does imply "rustic, folksy American"). It's also a true statement, but I can honestly say that I can't imagine a context where anyone would use the ditransitive construction with ***trick*** meaning the round of play itself (as opposed to a con, ruse, misleading play or bid, etc.). Besides which, deliberately misleading bids are generally considered "illegal" in bridge.

Comment: Just meant to say the google  might have some misleading data, wasn’t advocating any cheating.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. The following is not a natural way of saying that he played a joke ***on*** Mary.

> Tom played Mary a joke.

As a native speaker, the instant I saw the title I thought, "What equipment did he use to play the joke on? His mobile phone maybe?"

If you play [person] a [thing] it means that you performed something, like a tune or a video.

**Examples**

Tom played Mary a tune. (He took out a musical instrument and played a tune ***for*** Mary)

Tom played Mary a joke. (He went onto Youtube and found someone telling jokes. He played the joke being told on that video ***for*** Mary)

Comment: One of the many examples where both sentences are correct, but one means something different than expected and is therefore rarely used. That's why counting how often a phrase is used doesn't tell you if it's right or wrong, only whether it is used often or not.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you. In fact when I was reading the question I also thought that *Tom played a joke on Mary* was more natural even before I read that in your question.

Comment: I wonder you are sure "Tom played Mary a joke." is grammatically correct and used even though it is used infrequently.And how about Tom played a joke to Mary?

Comment: @Fellix No, it's not correct. "Send", "give", "write" can do that -- "Tom gave Mary a gift" -- but not "play".

Comment: @Fellix From an English teacher: *I have never heard the phrase "play a little joke with" in the context you described. You can "play a joke on" someone or "joke with" someone but you can't joke with or play a joke on a thing.*

Comment: Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+him+a+joke%2Cplayed+a+joke+on+him&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplayed%20a%20joke%20on%20him%3B%2Cc0) to start you off, then. The list of verbs you can do that reversal with is not long.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I use it, english teachers agree and I agree

Comment: Actually, @LukeSawczak, the list of verbs you can do that with _is_ quite long if you include benefactives with "for". But I agree that it is not usual with "on".

Comment: @LukeS - I agree that "Tom played Mary a joke" sounds off, but disagree with your assertion that "play" cannot be used that way. _Tom played Mary a song._

Comment: @J.R. Quite right. It's unusual on its own, but perfectly fine in context. What if somebody plays a YouTube video of a comedian telling a joke? *I played her a joke while we waited for our food.*

Comment: You guys are right (in fact the list is open since at least part of it is based on verb structure). I overgeneralized. But yeah, this case is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You could naturally say 'Tom **told** Mary a joke' which, although different in meaning, is constructed the same way, and it is entirely natural.

Comment: Please stick to what the OP asked and please don’t change the meaning. Thanks